# getting error when enter uri for timeseries ingest

Tags: time-series, timeserieschart

Hi I am trying to save data in timeseries db but I am facing an error at timeseries ingest when I enter wss://gateway-predix-data-services.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/v1/stream/messages in websocket uri it shows an error like this when I click on open socket

> ```
> The request failed with status code: 500   
>  {
>   "error": "Error: unexpected server response (401)",
>   "url": "wss://gateway-predix-data-services.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/v1/stream/messages"
> }
> ```

and see this screenshot once.
[image]
Thanks&regards
Eswar G

Answer (score 0):

From the error log, it looks you got authorization error. Check if you are using correct predix-zone-id of the time-series instance in the request header or you have configured correct UAA instance in predix tool kit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your UAA client with timeseries authorities?
To inserting time series data with particular user or client need permission. For getting permission, you need to add authorities into your UAA client.

Following are the authorities for timeseries.

[image]

[image: Update client in Predix Tool Kit]

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing a similar problem. I'm posting only one of several received error messages.  I've cycled through combos of the following for uri and zone id:

uri:
wss://gateway-predix-data-services.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/v1/stream/messages
https://time-series-store-predix.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/v1/datapoints

zone-id:
44853a54-3ecd-4589-85da-b54f2fda7cce
and the zone id shown in the photo, with .ingest at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so, 401 unauthorized.

Did you happen to re-create the timeseries or uaa?  Perhaps they are not associated.  Also, I'm assuming you did "login as client" in the top menu.

Might be a good idea to create a new timeseries tied to that uaa.  Then use the new zoneId.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add predix..ingest and predix..user to the scope and authorities section in uaa client in your predix.io account. Please check the client id to add permission for in websocketriver.config file.